# ctrlp : open selected file in the left vertical split

Tags: vim, ctrlp

When using ctrlp, I can open a selected file in a new vertical split using ctlr-v

However, the new file open in the left split and the already opened one goes to the right split. I'd like the opposite to happen : opening the new file in the right split.

Workaround : Using ctrl-w + ctrl-r afer opening the file to invert splits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create the setting in your vimrc:

```
set splitright
```

it will open every file you open in a vertical split on the right side (not only CtrlP).

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `<c-v>` to open file in vertical split.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm a few years late here, but from the plugin :help docs, it says that you can configure the new tab position:

***a** - after.

**b** - before.

**c** - the current tab page.

**l** - the last tab page.

**f** - the first tab page.*

For your desired behaviour, you should include this in your .vimrc or the configuration file of your editor.

```
let g:ctrlp_tabpage_position = 'ac'
```

I hope that someone in the future find this useful.